# isotope multiple filter 1 then filter 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am having trouble getting my isotope script to multi filter... user would select a **Location** (ex: Georgia all items would then be filter) and then user selects **Type** (ex: all selected Georgia content would then be filter by the type). The first filter is working but when the Type is selected its not just showing the selected living type. it just shuffles the list.

**Filter to sort**

```
  <select class="filters-select">
    <option value="*">Location</option>
    <option value="*">Any</option>
    <option value=".georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value=".maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value=".ncarolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value=".pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value=".virginia">Virginia</option>
  </select>
  <select class="filters-select2">
    <option value="*">Type</option>
    <option value=".apartments">Apartments</option>
    <option value=".mixeduse">Mixed Use</option>
    <option value=".student-housing">Student Housing</option>
    <option value=".senior-living">Senior Living</option>
  </select>
```

**Content to be sorted**

```
<div class="two-third portfolio-item georgia apartments" data-category="apartments">
    <h5 class="property-name"><span>apartments</span></h5>
  <p class="property-city">DECATUR, GEORGIA</p>
</div>            

<div class="one-third portfolio-item georgia apartments" data-category="apartments">
    <h5 class="property-name"><span>apartments</span></h5>
  <p class="property-city">LAWRENCEVILLE, GEORGIA</p>
</div>            

<div class="two-third portfolio-item pennsylvania student-housing" data-category="student-housing">
  <h5 class="property-name">student-housing</h5>
<p class="property-city">SHIPPENSBURG, PENNSYLVANIA</p>
</div>

<div class="one-third portfolio-item georgia student-housing" data-category="student-housing">
    <h5 class="property-name"><span>student-housing</span></h5>
  <p class="property-city">ATLANTA, GEORGIA</p>
</div>

<div class="two-third portfolio-item georgia student-housing" data-category="student-housing">
    <h5 class="property-name">student-housing</h5>
  <p class="property-city">KENNESAW, GEORGIA</p>
</div>            

<div class="one-third portfolio-item ncarolina mixeduse" data-category="mixeduse">
    <h5 class="property-name">mixeduse</h5>
  <p class="property-city">RALEIGH, NORTH CAROLINA</p>
</div>

<div class="two-third portfolio-item maryland mixeduse" data-category="mixeduse">
    <h5 class="property-name"><span>mixeduse</span></h5>
<p class="property-city">GAITHERSBURG, MARYLAND</p>
</div>

<div class="one-third portfolio-item ncarolina mixeduse" data-category="mixeduse">
    <h5 class="property-name">mixeduse</h5>
  <p class="property-city">CHARLOTTE, NORTH CAROLINA</p>
</div>

<div class="two-third portfolio-item georgia mixeduse" data-category="mixeduse">
    <h5 class="property-name"><span>mixeduse</span></h5>
  <p class="property-city">ATLANTA, GEORGIA</p>
</div>
```

**Isotope Script**

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};
// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select2').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```